# An analytic function $f$ on $|z|<1$ with $\sup_{|z|<1} |f(z)|=1$ and $|f(0)|=\frac{1}{2}$ has no zeros in $|z|<\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is an analytic function defined on $|z|<1$ such that $\sup_{|z|<1} |f(z)|=1$ and $|f(0)|=\frac{1}{2}$. How can I show that $f$ has no zeros in $|z|<\frac{1}{2}$? The only theorem I know about zeros of analytic functions is Rouche's theorem, but I can't see how to apply it in this case. Any hints?

Comment: Assume $f(0)=1/2$ and consider $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-1/2}{1-f(z)/2}$. Then $|g(z)| \leq |z|$ by Schwarz. If $f(z)=0$, then $|g(z)| = 1/2$ and $|z| \geq 1/2$.

Comment: @Mindlack: That is what the Schwarz-Pick theorem does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $f(a) = 0$ and apply the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem) to $f$ with $z_1= 0$ and $z_2 = a$:

$$
\left|{\frac  {f(0)-f(a)}{1-\overline {f(0)}f(a)}}\right|\leq \left|{\frac  {0 - a}{1-\overline {0}a}}\right| 
\iff \frac 12 \le |a|
$$

The example $f(z) = \frac{1/2 - z}{1-z/2}$ shows that the bound is sharp.

Comment: I didn’t know there was a formal, named, generalization for Schwarz’s theorem.